# Почему DataGrid не отображает все столбцы, загруженные из DataTable?

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, datatable

```
DataTable _fcDTable = new DataTable("DataTable: Frequency Converter");

// Инициализация столбцов таблицы
_fcDTable.Columns.Add(_timeColumnName);
_fcDTable.Columns[_timeColumnName].DataType = typeof(DateTime);

foreach (string name in FCParametersStructure.getParametersNames())
{
    _fcDTable.Columns.Add(name);
    _fcDTable.Columns[name].DataType = typeof(int);
}
```

При попытке привязать данные к таблице `DataGrid` следующим образом:

```
     TableWindow(DataTable dTable)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.dGrid.ItemsSource = dTable.DefaultView;        
                this.Show();
            }
```

...и даже убедившись, что данные всё-таки загружены:
[image: Контрольные значения]

...я обнаруживаю, что большая часть данных по какой-то причине не отображается вовсе:
[image: Отображение окна]

1. В чём причина такой отрисовки таблицы?
2. Стоит ли пользоваться
   `DataTable` в ситуации, когда приходится работать с сотнями тысяч
   записей? *(производительность при прокрутке оставляет желать лучшего)*
3. Какой класс лучше использовать для инициализации **неоднотипной** таблицы данных?

Comment: похоже что не выставлено AutoGenerateColumns="False", хотя названия колонок бредовые

Comment: Да, он в самом деле не выставлен, потому, что столбцы никаким другим образом в данном примере не создаются и загружаются они с правильными заголовками правильным числом. Вопрос в том, почему могли загрузиться только отдельные из них, хотя тип у всех, кроме первого 'DateTime' одинаковый ('int').

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какие поля куда мапятся, напишите каким образом у вас добавляются данные и что на выходе dTable.DefaultView.

Comment: Насколько мне помнится, то при ItemsSource используется рефлексия и тупо берется имя поля. У вас строка - это класс или просто массив объектов?

Comment: @Alexsandr Ter: строка здесь это инициализированная `DataRow row = _dTable.NewRow();`, полученная из `DataTable _dTable` со столбцами, инициализированными из некоторого списка `string[]`.

Comment: Я так думаю, что у вас отображаются автоматические имена переменных и вам надо создать класс и в него мапить данные из  string[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализация всей `DataGrid` через присваивание в его свойство `ItemsSource` объект `DataTable` чувствительна к наличию в именах столбцов **знаков препинания** (в данном случае `','`, `'.'`, `'/'`), и не выводит поля столбцов, в заголовках которых они наличествуют, на экран.

P.S.
*Построчная инициализация, на сколько я понял, невозможна, иначе как добавлением в коллекцию* `DataGrid.Items` *объекта, число свойств которого равно числу столбцов таблицы?*